# How can I edit filenames of txt files with batch

Tags: batch-file

I need a little help with my script

This is my working script

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d "%~dp0"

ECHO Working on your Cmlv (1).txt
Set /p Variable1=Enter value:
Set "Pattern1=(1)"
Set "Replace1=(%variable1%)"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "3Ready\(1) (Cmlv 1)*.txt"') DO (
    Set "File=%%~na"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern1%=%Replace1%!%%~xa"
)
ECHO Working on your Cmlv (1).txt
Set /p Variable2=Enter Value:
Set "Pattern2=(2)"
Set "Replace2=(%variable2%)"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "3Ready\(2) (Cmlv 1)*.txt"') DO (
    Set "File=%%~na"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern2%=%Replace2%!%%~xa"
)
ECHO Working on your Cmlv (1).txt
Set /p Variable3=Enter Value:
Set "Pattern3=(3)"
Set "Replace3=(%variable2%)"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "3Ready\(3) (Cmlv 1)*.txt"') DO (
    Set "File=%%~na"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern2%=%Replace2%!%%~xa"
)
```

This above script will only work on files with the filename `*(Cmlv 1)*`

So my goal is to make a script to handle every file related to their own `(Cmlv)`  
as you can see below each script will now work on it's own `cmlv`, but the script below will only work on files with patterns of (1) which does not help my other files

```
ECHO Working on your Cmlv (1).txt   < --------
Set /p Variable1=Enter Value:
Set "Pattern1=(1)"
Set "Replace1=(%variable1%)"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "3Ready\(*) (Cmlv 1)*.txt"') DO (
    Set "File=%%~na"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern1%=%Replace1%!%%~xa"
)
ECHO Working on your Cmlv (2).txt   < --------
Set /p Variable2=Enter Value:
Set "Pattern2=(1)"
Set "Replace2=(%variable1%)"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "3Ready\(*) (Cmlv 2)*.txt"') DO (
    Set "File=%%~na"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern2%=%Replace2%!%%~xa"
)
ECHO Working on your Cmlv (3).txt   < --------
Set /p Variable3=Enter Value:
Set "Pattern3=(1)"
Set "Replace3=(%variable1%)"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "3Ready\(*) (Cmlv 3)*.txt"') DO (
    Set "File=%%~na"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern3%=%Replace3%!%%~xa"
)
```

so I need help in updating my script to be able to do this function

(1) First I am trying to remove this line `Set "Pattern="` 
the reason for this is so that the script can focus on every file with `cmlv 1`
It would be great if this was possible `Set "Pattern=(*)` but I know that will not work

(2) Second thing how to place this to track every file `Set /p Variable2=Enter Value:` I was able to make this track files on other scripts but can't figure it out on this one

(3) so my plan is to make a script that will handle each `cmlv` and that each script will edit each file going from (1) to ????? what ever number

I have 50 cmlv files that is from `(1) cmlv.txt` to `(50) cmlv.txt` I'm ok with having 1 script per `cmlv`

OK, so in a folder I have these `.txt` files

```
My files <br>
(1) (Cmlv 1).txt
(2) (Cmlv 1).txt
(3) (Cmlv 1).txt
(4) (Cmlv 1).txt
(1) (Cmlv 2).txt
(2) (Cmlv 2).txt
(3) (Cmlv 2).txt
(4) (Cmlv 2).txt
(1) (Cmlv 3).txt
(2) (Cmlv 3).txt
(3) (Cmlv 3).txt
(4) (Cmlv 3).txt
```

and using my `%Variable%` I will manually enter numbers of my choosing 
so it can edit my files

so the script will find all `(cmlv 1)` and allow me to rename them using `%variable%`

after everything is found and rename the result should be like this 
the numbers in the these `( )` are always random that is why I am trying to use `%variable%`

```
My Results <br>
(35) (Cmlv 1).txt
(152) (Cmlv 1).txt
(265) (Cmlv 1).txt
(352) (Cmlv 1).txt
(398) (Cmlv 2).txt
(450) (Cmlv 2).txt
(650) (Cmlv 2).txt
(700) (Cmlv 2).txt
(721) (Cmlv 3).txt
(785) (Cmlv 3).txt
(902) (Cmlv 3).txt
(945) (Cmlv 3).txt
```

The numbers that are enter in here `( )` are based on a file the I have 
For example I have this file with this content in it

My other file `data.txt`

```
"name": 35
"Cmlv": 1

"name": 398
"Cmlv": 2

"name": 721
"Cmlv": 3
```

This of course is a smaller version of my content

I really do apricate your time and Thank you

I just want to add that this is what I am doing right now when I first started this task

```
:C1
@echo off

Set /p "Variable=Enter Value"

if exist "(1)(Cmlv1).txt" (
ren "(1)(Cmlv1).txt" "(%variable%).txt"
goto:C1
)
if exist "(2)(Cmlv1).txt" (
ren "(2)(Cmlv1).txt" "(%variable%).txt"
goto:C1
)
if exist "(3)(Cmlv1).txt" (
ren "(3)(Cmlv1).txt" "(%variable%).txt"
goto:C1
)
if exist "(4)(Cmlv1).txt" (
ren "(4)(Cmlv1).txt" "(%variable%).txt"
goto:C1
)
if exist "(5)(Cmlv1).txt" (
ren "(5)(Cmlv1).txt" "(%variable%).txt"
)
```

this is a very long way to make my task work

Comment: I note you have not yet received any responses, so I feel you should attempt better to address possible misunderstandings in your question information, not least with the possible names of the target files. You have used `cmlv 1.txt`, `(1) (Cmlv 1).txt`, `(1) (Cmlv 1) Copy.txt`, `(1) (Cmlv 1) Copy Copy Copy Copy.txt`. Perhaps a better representation of before and after filenames, to cover every possible pattern you are likely to encounter within the chosen tree structure. Without the clarity of a filename pattern as the foundation for your task, any renaming process is already compromised.

Comment: @Compo - Thank you I will try my best to update the question, will you be able to help me after I update it

Comment: @Compo - Thank you I have updated the question can you take a look to see if it make sense

Comment: `File Editing` implies changing the contents of the files, not their names. You might want to clarify.

Comment: When you want random, you should use `!random!` instead of `set /p`. and adapt the range to your needs (like `set /a variable=!random! %% 1000`, which generates numbers between `0` and `999`). Don't forget to check `if exist ...` before renaming.

Comment: @Stephan Yes I was going to add If Exist, but the numbers are manually entered by me, the numbers are a based on content found in file, I read a file and  that has `name: 35 cmlv: 50` so I take the number in the name section and enter it here `(XXX) (Cmlv 1).txt` in the X

Comment: I have added a little bit more info to my question, on where I get the numbers from

Comment: about your last edit: you are sure you want to rename several files to the very same name? That will not work. Btw: when I said `if exist` in my last comment, I meant to check the *destination* name to not overwrite it. You already know the source name exists.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon what you currently have as your question, does this script help you any?

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Set "PATHEXT=" ^& %SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe /R
 "%~dp03Ready" "(?*) (Cmlv ?*).txt" 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe
 /RIC:"\\([0123456789][0123456789]*) (Cmlv [123456789])\.txt$"
 /C:"\\([0123456789][0123456789]*) (Cmlv [1234][0123456789])\.txt$"
 /C:"\\([0123456789][0123456789]*) (Cmlv 50)\.txt$"') Do (Set "File=%%~nG"
    For /F "Tokens=1,3 Delims=()" %%H In ("%%~nG"
    ) Do Call :Sub "%%G" %%~xG %%H)
Pause
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
Echo Working on %~1 
Set /P "Replacement=Enter value to replace %3 in (%3) >"
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
If %Replacement% NEq %3 If Exist "%~dp1!File:(%3)=(%Replacement%)!%2" (Echo(
    Echo File %~dp1!File:(%3^)=(%Replacement%^)!%2 already exists^!
    Echo(
    GoTo Sub)
Ren %1 "!File:(%3)=(%Replacement%)!%2"
Echo(
Exit /B
```

---

To create a test environment, navigate to somewhere which doesn't already have a `3Ready` directory in the current working directory, then run the following to create and show it:

```bash
@Echo Off
Rem Create a test environment:
MD "3Ready\Sub1\Sub1-1"
MD "3Ready\Sub2\Sub2-1"
MD "3Ready\Sub2\Sub2-1\Sub2-1-1"
MD "3Ready\Sub3"
CD.>"3Ready\(1) (Cmlv 1).txt"
CD.>"3Ready\Sub3\(2) (Cmlv 1).txt"
CD.>"3Ready\Sub1\(3) (Cmlv 1).txt"
CD.>"3Ready\Sub2\Sub2-1\(4) (Cmlv 1).txt"
CD.>"3Ready\Sub2\(1) (Cmlv 2).txt"
CD.>"3Ready\Sub2\Sub2-1\(2) (Cmlv 2).txt"
CD.>"3Ready\Sub3\(3) (Cmlv 2).txt"
CD.>"3Ready\(4) (Cmlv 2).txt"
CD.>"3Ready\(1) (Cmlv 3).txt"
CD.>"3Ready\Sub2\Sub2-1\Sub2-1-1\(2) (Cmlv 3).txt"
CD.>"3Ready\Sub1\Sub1-1\(3) (Cmlv 3).txt"
CD.>"Ready\Sub2\Sub2-1\(4) (Cmlv 3).txt"
Rem Add a few non matching files too:
CD.>"3Ready\Sub1\(3)(Cmlv 2).txt"
CD.>"3Ready\Sub2\(B) (Cmlv 2).txt"
CD.>"3Ready\Sub2\Sub2-1\Sub2-1-1\(4) (Cmlv 53).txt"
Rem Show the test environment:
%SystemRoot%\System32\tree.com /A /F "3Ready"
Pause
```

Now run the topmost script, and remember that you must insert at the prompt only numbers in the format you showed in your question, here they are, as a reminder, `35`, `152`, `265`, `352`, `398`, `450`, `650`, `700`, `721`, `785`, `902`, `945`. Those are two and tree digit numbers consisting only of integers, *(none of which begin with a zero)*.

Comment: OK, so it failed to rename the file, this is Regex I'm terrible at this - is this correct `where.exe`

Comment: It works perfectly based on the information you specificalky used, after I asked you to clarify the filenames. I had a PC available, up until half an hour ago, created a tree with your matching filenames, and tested it multiple times, it worked flawlessly. If you are getting no output, you lied about the filenames, if you are entering the values and the files are not being renamed, then you do not have the required permissions to do so. The code however does work exactly as I intended, and according to your specifications, with no modification whatsoever. I do not support changes to my code.

Comment: Really OK Thank you, and your code is a lot for me to figure out how to even start to change it, but I will try again, maybe I did something wrong

Comment: To clarify the last part of the previous comment @Hot-Topic, you would only be messing with the findstr.exe matches, if you thought that you could be untruthful about your specifcations, then play with my code to suit your purposes. How about you do the same thing I had to do, create a tree within a directory named `3Ready` placed alongside the batch script. Fill it with files named exactly as the ones in your question, then run the code. You should not tell me my code doesn't work, when you have modified it and/or your requirements. Please test it correctly using the same information I had.

Comment: That is exactly how I have it - it's so weird for some reason it doesn't work for me, man it would be great if I could load a link to a video or screenshots to show you that I have it exactly the way as I asked it, it opens the CMD it shows me that I am editing `(1) (Cmlv 1).txt` and to change it from (1) to ??? and I enter the number and it closes, nothing happens

Comment: If you told us the number(s) you've tried and failed with @Hot-Topic, then perhaps one or more of us could test it! Also if you change `Off` to `On` and run the script straight fron the Command Prompt, you'd have the output to check, and post, if need be.

Comment: As a courtesy @Hot-Topic, I have gone back to the workshop today to test the code again on a Windows PC. I created the test environment again, using the code I have submitted as an edit to my answer, and ran the script copied directly from top of the answer too. There was absolutely no issues in running it or it functioning as intended and the deliberately created, unmatching files were not prompted for rename either!

Comment: Thank you - Question and you just double click the script and that's it right- because I used your environment builder and I recopied your script and it all it did was close - and yes I was entering 100 for the first number (1) to (100)

Comment: I think @Hot-Topic, because my bias, after taking the time to write all of this up, and to specifically travel to the workshop on my day off for you, may be misunderstood as outside of the acceptable guidelines of this site, I will allow others to test it on this occasion, and provide their feedback. The code works without modification as now tested on more than one PC. Your issue cannot therefore be reproduced by me, and since you have not submitted all of the output from having run the script with `Echo On` and directly from within a Command Prompt, `cmd.exe`, window, I cannot help you more.